# Firestore, how to merge indexes for queries containing multiple range comparisons?

Tags: firebase, react-native, indexing, filter, google-cloud-firestore

So each document of my collection contains five different fields namely:

```
mode
type
category
price
size
```

I want my users to filter docs based on the above fields, i.e a user can filter results by trying any combination of the fields possible like:

```
mode=='foo' && type=='bar'
category=='foo' && price>500 && size<50
category=='bar'
...
...
```

this will lead to numerous different combination possibilities. However for fields `mode`, `category` and `type` the user can only filter based on  **equality condition**  while for fields `price` and `size` he can filter using **range comparisons**.

Moreover I also need the functionality to `orderBy` using price in both ascending and descending manner.

So for any filter applied a firebase query may contain up to 3 equality clauses and up to 2 range comparisons. This obviously means that I have to create appropriate **composite indexes** in the  firebase console to query data in this manner.

some examples of the queries are as follows:

```
db.where('price', '<', 2000).where('category','==','foo').where('size', '>', 80).orderBy('price', 'desc')
db.where('price', '>', 300).where('type','==','foo').where('mode', '==', 'bar').where('category', '==', 'foo').where('size', '<', 500).orderBy('price')
```

Since this will lead to quite a few number of indexes which will cost storage space, the firebase documentation suggests  [*merging indexes for equality clauses*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview?authuser=0#taking_advantage_of_index_merging)

Now my question is what is the best way to create composite indexes for the situation described above so that I can query the data using any of the combination as described above while creating least number of indexes in the console by taking advantage of the 'merge technique' of firestore.

I was wondering if i have to create indexes something like these:

```
mode (ascending), price (ascending)
type (ascending), price (ascending)
category (ascending), price (ascending)
size (ascending), price (ascending)

mode (ascending), price (descending)
type (ascending), price (descending)
category (ascending), price (descending)
size (ascending), price (descending)
```

The **problem** here is testing, as it is very hectic to test each and every query possible for the created indices.
So I was looking for a combination of indices that guarantees all the possible set of queries described above.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries can only contain a single range clause, so this type of query is not possible:

```
category=='foo' && price>500 && size<50
```

Comment: even after creating indices?